# @lru_cache и Рекурсия, как работает

Tags: python, функции, рекурсия

Сдаю информатику, 19 задание егэ. Никак не могу понять по какому алгоритму работает рекурсия и как она конкретно записывается в кеш.

ИЗ КАКОЙ СТУПЕНИ РЕКУРСИИ ВЫВОДИТСЯ 'B1' (к примеру если создам функцию в которой напишу две строки - return 1 и return 2, то после вызова выведется 1, тк почему то только первый обьявленный return возвращает). Там я во списковых включениях вызывается та же функция что и в описании, выходит рекурсия. Как вообще работает код? и простыми словами как @lru_cache записывает кеш? что за значение None? я это гуглю два дня уже, и по меркам егэ это непростительно продолжительное время
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Как я вижу алгоритм типа..]

```
    from functools import lru_cache

# ПО УСЛОВИЮ ЗАДАЧИ ДВА ИГРОКА И ДВЕ КУЧИ КАМНЕЙ
# ЗА ОДИН ХОД МОЖНО ДОБАВИТЬ 1 КАМЕНЬ В ОДНУ ИЗ КУЧ ИЛИ УМНОЖИТЬ ОДНУ ИЗ КУЧ ВДВОЕ
# В НАЧАЛЬНЫЙ МОМЕНТ В ПЕРВОЙ КУЧЕ 10, ВО ВТОРОЙ S (1 <= S <= 52)
# ИГРА КОНЧАЕТСЯ КОГДА СУММА ДВУХ КУЧ БОЛЬШЕ ИЛИ РАВНА 62
# А ПОБЕЖДАЕТ ИГРОК КОТОРЫЙ СДЕЛАЛ ПОСЛЕДНИЙ ХОД 


def move(h): # аргумент в данном случае будет всегда кортежом
    a, b = h
    return (a, b + 1), (a, b * 2), (b, a + 1), (b, a * 2) # Все вероятные ходы



@lru_cache(None) # кешируется значения рекурсий (не знаю как это работает поэтому и спрашиваю)

def game(h): 
    if sum(h) >= 62: # вот тут и начинаются все приколы
        return 'WIN'
    if any( game(m) == 'WIN' for m in move(h) ):
        return 'B1' # а вот тут они заканчиваются ... (ПОБЕДА ПЕРВОГО ИГРОКА)

for S in range(1, 52):
    if game( (1, S) ) is not None:
        print('{}: {}'.format(S, game( (10, S) ) ))

print(game.cache_info()) # Пытался что гуглить буду, но ниче не нашёл понятного
```

Comment: Код приводят форматированным ТЕКСТОМ

Comment: Код текстом в вопрос, только мат из комментариев уберите, а то ещё хуже всё будет.

Comment: @CrazyElf приношу дикие извинения, я масля на форуме, в крайнем случае обратился.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятно, какой именно `None` вам непонятен. Если как параметр декоратора `lru_cache`, то это просто означает, что размер кэша не ограничен. Если задать кэшу ограничение на кол-во хранимых элементов, то при необходимости положить в кэш ещё одно значение и заполненности кэша до этого указанного значения `LRU cache` посмотрит у себя статистику - какой из элементов кэша запрашивался наиболее давно - и выкинет этот элемент, чтобы добавить новый. Таким образом, размер кэша никогда не будет больше, чем указанный.

А если вас интересует `None` как результат работы кэшируемой функции, то `None` будет возвращён, если в вашей функции не сработают оба `if` и значит не сработает ни один из `return`. В питоне если функция закончилась, а `return` ни один не выполнился, то считается, что как будто выполнился `return None`. Такая договорённость. Ничего не вернувшая функция считается вернувшей `None`.

Что касается самого кэша, то всё просто. При обращении к кэшированной функции декоратор проверяет - если был уже вызов этой функции с такими же точно аргументами, то функция не выполняется, а берётся результат из словаря декоратора, в котором ключ - это аргументы функции, а значение - это то, что вернула функция, когда её вызвали с такими аргументами.
Если же в кэше нет таких аргументов, то функция выполняется и после её выполнения аргументы и результат запоминаются в словаре-кэше.
Ну, пока хватает выделенного под кэш размера словаря. Если же места не хватает - см. первый абзац этого ответа, что в этом случае происходит.

Метод `cache_info` показывает статистику:

- сколько раз кэш сработал удачно (в кэше нашлись аргументы и он вернул значение не выполняя функцию)
- сколько раз кэш "промахнулся" (пришлось таки вызвать функцию, чтобы получить результат и запомнить его потом в кэше)
- какой был задан максимальный размер для кэша функции
- сколько элементов на данный момент хранится в кэше декоратора этой функции

Судя по вашей статистике, кэш вам сэкономил примерно половину обращений к функции. С учётом того, что у вас тут есть рекурсия, возможно, экономия была ещё больше - невозможно посчитать, сколько было бы рекурсивных вызовов функции, которые отсёк кэширующий декоратор в случае попадания в кэш. Это только если вы посчитаете каким-то счётчиком сколько раз вызвалась функция без декоратора и сколько с декоратором, тогда узнаете настоящую статистику.

P.S. Попробовал запустить без декоратора, подождал несколько минут, не дождался никакого вывода, но счётчик обращений к функции `game` уже превысил 200 миллионов. Так что на самом деле кеширующий декоратор играет тут решающую роль, без него этот код вообще не выполнится за разумное время.

Comment: А если у меня выполняется два if в функции game, то что будет возвращать функция? почему не 'win'?

Comment: @ЛендВульпбп Если выполнится какой-то из `if`, то конечно функция вернёт то, что написано в `return` у выполнившегося `if`. То есть выполнится либо один из `return` и что у него там написано вернуть, либо никакой из них и тогда вернётся `None`.